# I want to check text validate when tap button

Tags: rx-swift

I want to check text validate when tap button. If validate failure, it will show error text on UILabel and do not send request. Else if validate success, it will send request.

I see many demo about login, but they control button enabled to avoid validate data when tap button. I am puzzled with it.

I have write some code.

```
class LoginViewModel: BaseViewModel, ViewModelType {
    struct Input {
        let loginTaps: Driver<Void>
    }
    struct Output {
        let validatedUsername: Driver<Bool>
        let validatedPassword: Driver<Bool>
    }

    let username = BehaviorRelay(value: "")
    let password = BehaviorRelay(value: "")
    let loginTapped = PublishSubject<Void>()

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {

        let validatedUsername = username.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "").map { username in
            return username.isPhoneNumber
        }

        let validatedPassword = password.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "").map { password in
            return password.count > 7
        }

        input.loginTaps.map { () -> Void in
            <#code#>
            // I want do check and then do network request
        }

        input.loginTaps.drive(onNext: { [weak self] () in
                self?.loginTapped.onNext(())
            }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        loginTapped.flatMapLatest { _  -> Observable<RxSwift.Event<Token>> in

           // and if I want to return Bool not Token, how should I do????????????

            return self.provider.login(username: self.username.value, password: self.password.value)
                .asObservable()
                .materialize()
            }.subscribe(onNext: { (event) in
                switch event {
                case .next(let token):
                    AuthManager.setToken(token: token)
                case .error(let error):
                    log.error(error.localizedDescription)
                default: break
                }
            }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        return Output(validatedUsername: validatedUsername,
                      validatedPassword: validatedPassword)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect to see something like this:

```
class LoginViewModel {
    struct Input {
        let loginTap: Signal<Void>
        let username: Driver<String>
        let password: Driver<String>
    }

    struct Output {
        let errorText: Driver<String>
        let loginSuccess: Signal<Void>
    }

    var networkRequest: (URLRequest) -> Observable<Data> = { _ in fatalError("need to replace this with an implementation.") }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {

        func isValidCredentials(username: String, password: String) -> Bool {
            return username.isPhoneNumber && password.count > 7
        }

        let credentials = Driver.combineLatest(input.username, input.password)

        // this chain emits when the login button is tapped and the credentials are invalid
        let invalidInputError = input.loginTap
            .withLatestFrom(credentials)
            .filter { !isValidCredentials(username: $0, password: $1) }
            .map { _ in "Credentials are invalid" }
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError("can't get here") })

        let networkRequest = self.networkRequest // to avoid dealing with `self` in the flatMap below

        // this chain makes a request if the login button is tapped while the credentials are valid
        let loginResult = input.loginTap
            .withLatestFrom(credentials)
            .filter { isValidCredentials(username: $0, password: $1) }
            .map { URLRequest.login(username: $0, password: $1) }
            .asObservable()
            .flatMapLatest { networkRequest($0).materialize() }
            .share(replay: 1)

        // this chain emits when the login result produces an error
        let loginError = loginResult
            .map { $0.error }
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0!.localizedDescription }
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError("can't get here") })

        // this chain emits when the login result succeeds
        let loginSuccess = loginResult
            .filter { $0.element != nil }
            .map { _ in }
            .asSignal(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError("can't get here") })

        let errorText = Driver.merge(invalidInputError, loginError)

        return Output(errorText: errorText, loginSuccess: loginSuccess)
    }
}
```

Comment: when does `onErrorRecover` completion gets called & why `fatalError` is put over there?

Comment: The `onErrorRecover` completion never gets called which is why `fatalError` is put in there.

Comment: can I write `let this = self` outside the `flatMap` and then use `this.something` inside `flatMap` or `map`. Will that solve the problem if there are multiple functions and variables involved?

Comment: How can I achieve Two-way binding in this?

Comment: The reason why I wanted because on any error occurs I wanted to clear the password from textField.

Comment: Writing `let this = self` outside the flatMap will still strongly capture self. Move `something` out of self so you don't have to worry about capturing self.

Comment: Clearing the password doesn't require two-way binding. Just another observable in the output that emits an empty string when you want the clear to happen. Then bind the passwordTextField.rx.text to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221872/discussion-between-anirudha-mahale-and-daniel-t).

Comment: Yeah but what if I hit the login button again then `input.password` will give the previous password to the credentials in the `transform` method. I don't think `input.password` will have an empty string in this case.